# PHP Column Styling

Tags: php, css, html-table

I need my table to include submissions into three columns then a new row start with three more columns, etc. So submission 1, first column, submission 2, second column, submission 3, 3 column. Then a new row and the process starts again. (HTML Example Code below)

Every time I try with my php code my page comes up blank so I am missing something somewhere.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, name, website, url, email, date, description FROM basic";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows>0){
    <tr> 
    while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<table><tr><th><b>Company:</b> " . $row["name"]. "</th></tr><tr><td>     
        <b>URL:</b> <a href='".$row["url"]."'>".$row["url"]."</a></td></tr><tr><td> 
        <b>Email:</b> " . $row["email"]. "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Launch Date:</b> " .    
        $row["date"]. "</td></tr><tr><td><b>Announcement:</b> " .   
$row["description"]. "</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Example: This is what I am trying to get it to look like.

```
<style>
table, td, th {    
    border: 10px solid #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
}

table {
    border-collapse: initial;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    padding: 15px;
    width: 25%;
    line-height: 2;
}

th {
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 25%; 
}
</style>

<body>
    <table class="ex1">
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Company</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <b>URL:</b><br>
            <b>Location:</b><br>
            <b>Inductry:</b><br>
            <b>Start Date:</b><br>
            <b>Announcement:</b><br> 
            <br>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>URL:</b><br>
            <b>Location:</b><br>
            <b>Inductry:</b><br>
            <b>Start Date:</b><br>
            <b>Announcement:</b><br> 
            <br>
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>URL:</b><br>
            <b>Location:</b><br>
            <b>Inductry:</b><br>
            <b>Start Date:</b><br>
            <b>Announcement:</b><br> 
            <br>
        </td>
    </table>
```

Comment: echo $result->num_rows;

Comment: Please confirm that your expected result will be exactly same as you have mentioned in your question at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code is not generating HTML in proper format. Please try below:

```
// Query executed here and resultset returned

if ($result->num_rows>0){
    echo "<table>";
    while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><th><b>Company:</b> " . $row["name"]. "</th></tr>
              <tr><td><b>URL:</b> <a href='".$row["url"]."'>".$row["url"]."</a></td></tr>
              <tr><td><b>Email:</b> " . $row["email"]. "</td></tr>
              <tr><td><b>Launch Date:</b> " . $row["date"]. "</td></tr>
              <tr><td><b>Announcement:</b> " . $row["description"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to take the top code and make each new entry go into columns with a max of three columns (Example: column 1 column 2 column 3) then loop back for 4-6, etc. I have tried multiple examples from Stackoverflow and the internet and nothing seems to work. Thanks.